# Spreadsheet App Script (sendeditNotification)

Tags: google-apps-script

I created this function/coding in order to receive email should there is changes in a certain column. I only received a failure email, and after that, no furhter email received. Here are the function,

```
function sendEditNotification(e){

if (e.range.columnStart != 11 || e.value != "Expired") return;
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,4).getValues();
let station = rData[0][3];
let msg = "Business license of " + station + " has expired.";
Logger.log(msg);
MailApp.sendEmail("My Email", "Hub Business License", msg)
}
```

I have checked the execution logs, and the logs is empty.

And here are the email from the app script itself on the error

Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets)

FYI the sheet is mine.Please help

Tried to search multiple website on the matter, no solution yet

Comment: In order to correctly understand your current issue, I have 2 questions. 1. How do you run your function? 2. Are you restricting the scopes by manifest file (`appsscript.json`)?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I am very new at this. What I did here is basically copying what is taught on this website, https://www.lido.app/tutorials/google-sheets-send-email-based-on-cell-value.

What I aim to achieve is, once column K changes to the word "Expired", automatically the Google sheet will trigger an email to notify me.

As for the 2nd question, sorry, I do not understand it. I do not have any background in programming nor related fields. Sorry

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand the answers to my 2 questions. But, I would like to try to understand your reply. When I could correctly understand your situation, I would like to think of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran your script and confirmed that it is working. The issue most likely lies with the permissions authorized for the script. I suggest checking this [page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) to confirm if your script has the correct permissions. The Apps Script project should have the permission `See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets`. You should see the name of the Apps Script project on that page if permissions were properly authorized for your account.

As an alternative, you can also remove your existing `From spreadsheet - On edit` trigger then add it back again. If permissions were not properly granted previously, you will be prompted to authorize the script. Let me know if this helps.

### Reference

[Apps Script Authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)

Comment: Hi commoners, was the answer above able to fix your issue? 

Feel free to let us know if you're still encountering problems with your script or to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you.